# Why is my error message not echoing to the screen?

Tags: php

When the user submits a form, the PHP will check to see if the $post was empty, if so, it will set an $error_message variable; thus database INSERT query will not execute. I then attempt to show the error message further on in the code, however it will not display. I have been trying to figure this out for hours and I still cannot find the solution. The funny thing is, this used to work, however I must have implemented something in this file which is preventing the code to execute correctly.

Why is my error message not echoing to the screen (last few lines of code show attempt to echo the error_message)?

```
<?php require("inc/db.php"); ?>
<?php include("inc/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include ("inc/ChromePhp.php"); ?>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
session_start();
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
  header("Location: ?id=".getUserId($_SESSION['U_Email']));
}
if(isset($_SESSION["U_Email"])) {
  $usersData = getUserInfo($_GET['id']);
  $postCount = getPostCount($_GET['id']);
} else {
  header('Location: login.php');
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $post = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"user_post",FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

  if($post == "") {
    $error_message = "Please enter something before submitting";
  }

  if(!isset($error_message)) {
    $post = $db->real_escape_string($post);
    $postStore = $db->query("INSERT INTO `Post`(P_Body, P_Dateadded, User_U_ID) VALUES ('{$post}', NOW(), '{$_SESSION['U_ID']}' )");
  }
}

$dashNav = true;
$cap = true;
$pageTitle = 'Profile';
$name = $usersData['U_Forename'] . " " . $usersData['U_Surname'];
$gender = $usersData['U_Gender'];
$bio = $usersData['U_Biography'];
$team = $usersData['U_Team'];
$city = $usersData['U_City'];
include("inc/header.php");
?>

  <?php if(userExists($_GET['id'])) { ?>
  <section>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <?php
      if($_SESSION['U_ID'] != $_GET['id']) {
        $testFollow = "SELECT `Following`.F_ID, `Following`.U_ID FROM `Following`
        WHERE U_ID = '{$_SESSION['U_ID']}' AND F_ID = '{$_GET['id']}'";
        $testFollowResult = $db->query($testFollow);
        if ($testFollowResult->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<button class='lift' href='#'>Unfollow Driver</button>";
        } else {
          echo "<button class='lift' href='#'>Follow Driver</button>";
        }
      }
      ?>

      <?php if (isset($error_message)) {
        // This code will not echo!
        echo "<h2>".$error_message."</h2>";
      }
  ?>
</div>

<div class="section-b">
 <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-wd-12">
    <div class="col">
     <form id="share" name="share" action="profile.php" method="post">
     <textarea id="post" name="user_post" placeholder="What's happening?">    </textarea>
     <span id="errorpost" class="error">You must input something something before sending</span>
     <?php
     echo "<div class='g-recaptcha' data-     sitekey='6LfNTB0TAAAAAKEw9zfnFzvGCXF9MuYTkdB144x1
     '></div>"; ?>
   <button onclick="return postCheckValidate();"        type="submit">Share</button>
 </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are there been any PHP/MySQL errors being shown on the page or logged into the error log?

Comment: Can you provide the form?

Comment: Is it doing one of the `Location:` redirects? If you redirect, you don't see anything from the original page.

Comment: No PHP or MySQL errors @LMS94 - any PHP validation check I do works and stops the query from inserting, however the message just will not echo!

Comment: @Barmar No redirect, page refreshes with PHP validation working, if I share a post with nothing inside, the page will just refresh and nothing will be inserted into the DB. I tested other validation techniques as well such as strlen($post) < 5, if only 4 are shared, then it still works, it just will not see the $error_message variable

Comment: Form provided @JonStirling

Comment: Is ?id=x appended to the url you're posting to as there is a php if statement wrapped around where the error message would be shown.. <?php if(userExists($_GET['id'])) { ?>

Comment: @LMS94 Yeah, that's all configured fine, I even removed that line of code to see if it would make a difference and it's still the same :/

Comment: Could you put die; after the echo to see if the h2 element is being hidden somehow?

Comment: @LMS94 Still nothing

Comment: var_dump(userExists($_GET['id'])). What does that return?

Comment: Returns bool(true) @Cloud_Ratha

Comment: If I try var_dump($error_message) it just returns an undefined variable... I just don't understand how, it's clearly defined!

Comment: Perhaps one of your requires is using the same variable name?

Comment: @Cloud_Ratha Just had a check and this is not the case :(